# How to dynamically add fields of document of certain collection in Firestore using Map in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

I have DatabaseService class in which I maintain and update data. I am using map to dynamicaaly update data of document of certain collection in firebase but I am unable to successfully update all the data I am using simple forEach to fetch data from Map and store it in firebase

```
import 'package:home_crisp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  // collection reference is just reference for certain collection

  final CollectionReference chefCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('chef');

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  Future updateChefData(Map<String, dynamic> dataMap) async {
    // await chefCollection.document(uid).setData({
    //   'chefName': chefName,
    //   'chefPhNo': chefPhNo,
    //   'chefDateOfBirth': chefDateOfBirth,
    // });
    dataMap.forEach(
      (key, value) async {
        await chefCollection.document(uid).setData({
          key: value,   // Key represent the field key and value is actual value of firebase document i.e. chefName: "Peter" 
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

In "chefRegistration" class I am encapsulating values in a Map and sending them to updateChefData function in dataServices

```
class chefRegistration extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _chefRegistrationState createState() => _chefRegistrationState();
}
class _chefRegistrationState extends State<chefRegistration> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

// ~
// ~
// Some Code
// ~ 
// ~


FlatButton(
   onPressed: () async {
   Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = {
                'chefName': this.chefName,
                'chefPhNo': this.phoneNo,
                'chefDateOfBirth': this.dateOfBirth,
               };

                await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateChefData(dataMap);
   }
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the way I want it to work

[image]

But the problem is that it only update last field of document which is dateOfBirth

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use [updateData()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/updateData.html) instead of setData().  Or, you can pass `merge: true` as the second argument to [setData()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html).